# EDE generated makefile set variable using ?=

Tags: emacs, cedet

Is there a way to set via the EDE customization buffers a variable in Make makefile that will be assigned using `?=` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature isn't explicitly supported in EDE.  You can, however, create your own support makefile called whatever you want with your own hand-written make rules, and then include it into the generated Makefile using the include file slot.